# Setting angular.js controller variable from within a directive without ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to set the selected option's text to a controller variable exactly like how ngModel does this for the value attribute of the selected option.

```html
<div ng-controller="Subjects as ctrl">
  <select ng-model="ctrl.model.fieldId" text-model="ctrl.model.fieldName">
    <option value="1">yes</option>
    <option value="2">no</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

how can I set the `ctrl.model.fieldName` to `yes` for example if the first option was selected which is not a function from within the directive? this directive have to work alongside ngModel.

I want a way without using ngOptions because I don't have any values array in my javascript, although I can parse the HTML and create one.

This the directive so far:

```js
(function () {
    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('TextModel', TextModel);
    function TextModel($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
                elem.on('change', selectChanged);
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    elem.off('change', selectChanged);
                });
                function selectChanged() {
                    var selectedText = elem.find('option:selected').text();
                    //YAY! I have the selected option's text
                    console.log(selectedText);
                    //now how can I set ctrl.model.fieldName = selectedText ??
                }
            }
        };
    };

})();
```

Comment: can you share controller and directives code ??

Comment: Controller is very simple and  `ctrl.model.fieldName` is a string variable, directive is the subject of this question and nonexistent

Comment: added a simple directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another directive for that.

It will be better to bind your select options to {key : value} array, or any other objects array

See here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Then, you can bind your ng-model to the selected item.

```
$scope.items = [
    {key : 1 , value : 'yes'},
    {key : 2 , value : 'no'}
]

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.value for item in items"></select>
```

[Demo on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20087)

**Updated:**

If you want to use your own directive for this, you can use isolated scope like this:

```
function TextModel($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
            'textModel' : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attr ) {
            elem.on('change', selectChanged);
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                elem.off('change', selectChanged);
            });
            function selectChanged() {

                var selectedText = $(elem).find('option:selected').text();
                //YAY! I have the selected option's text

                //now how can I set ctrl.model.fieldName = selectedText ??
                scope.textModel = selectedText;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

BTW, your directive setter should be:

```
.directive('textModel', TextModel);
```

instead of :

```
.directive('TextModel', TextModel);
```

[Demo on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20088)

Comment: I am willing to avoid that because the html is given to me exactly as I have mentioned, I can parse the html and create the array if all other things have failed

Comment: If you want to use special directive for this, you can use isolated scope , see working example with your directive : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20088/